# Delete files in python that contain a number anywhere in the file name

Tags: python

I have a directory containing .jpg files and I need to delete all files within this directory containing a number anywhere in the file name.

I've used os.listdir to specify the path. I was then able to use fnmatch.fnmatch to only delete something specific like "3453.jpg", but I need it to delete something like thomas9.jpg or thom43as.jpg. Basically any file name containing a number needs to be deleted.

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Can you post what you tried so far..?

Comment: I suggest you use a regular expression (module `re`) to check if the file name contains a number. Something like `.*[0-9]+.*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `re` module.

```
import os
import re


for _file in os.listdir('.'):
    if re.search('\d.*\.jpg$', _file):
        print(_file)
```

Comment: The `_file.split()` is unnecessary if a regex pattern such as `r'\d.*\.jpg$'` is used.

Comment: @zetysz: `\d` is sufficient for a match. The leading `.*` is not necessary because you are using `re.search()`. Try it out.

Answer (score 2):

`regex` is not really necessary in your case, if you want to delete any file with filename containing any digits, then you can do it simply this way:

```
import os

my_path = 'path_to_your_directory'
any_digit = '1234567890'

os.chdir(my_path) #Just to be sure you are in your working directory not else where!

for f in os.listdir('.'):
    if any(x in f for x in any_digit) and f.endswith('.jpg'):
        os.remove(f)
```

You can also use `string` module and then:

```
import os
import string

my_path = 'path_to_your_directory'

os.chdir(my_path) #Just to be sure you are in your working directory not else where!

for f in os.listdir('.'):
    if any(x in f for x in string.digits) and f.endswith('.jpg'):
        os.remove(f)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`glob()/iglob()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.glob) is slightly easier than using a regex:

```
import glob
import os

def delete_files(path, pattern):
    for f in glob.iglob(os.path.join(path, pattern)):
        try:
            os.remove(f)
        except OSError as exc:
            print exc

>>> delete_files('/tmp', '*[0-9]*.jpg')
```

`os.remove()` should be called within a `try/except` block in case the file can not be removed, e.g. insufficient permissions, in use by another process, the file is a directory etc.

Using regex, if there are many files it could be worth compiling the pattern outside of the loop:

```
import os
import re

def delete_files(path, pattern):
    pattern = re.compile(pattern)
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        if pattern.search(f):
            try:
                os.remove(os.path.join(path, f))
            except OSError as exc:
                print exc

delete_files('/tmp', r'\d.*\.jpg$')
```

Comment: @zetysz: No. That's correct. One digit followed by zero or more characters (which might include other digits). This is OK because `re.search()` matches anywhere within the string, although there is little harm in specifying a fuller pattern such as `^.*\d.*\.jpg$` which matches the beginning of the line.

Comment: Oh, you removed your invalid comment about the regex pattern. But you are right that the file can't always be deleted (unless path is the same as the current directory). Fixed.